# How to disable logout (always shutdown instead) in xfce4?

Tags: centos, x11, configuration, xfce, kiosk

I'm using XFCE on CentOS to make a kiosk. The only thing I have on the desktop is a panel on the top with some programs. It already auto-logins at boot and, at the end of the session, I want the user to be able only to shutdown. However, there is still a "log out" button when right-clicking the panel and I just can't find the configuration file to get rid of this button. I have already searched almost every config file but couldn't find one for the panel-right-click-menu.
Another option I have is disabling logout entirely, but I don't know how to go about that.

Comment: You could change your window manager or desktop.

Answer (score 1):

XFCE4 is supposed to have a "kiosk" mode that lets you disable logout. Alternately, you can make the "Logout" command run shutdown instead. Here's an example from CCC at https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6846:

Change the file `/usr/share/applications/xfce4-session-logout.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now
Icon=system-log-out
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Categories=System;X-XFCE;X-Xfce-Toplevel;
OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
Name=Log Out
```